# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpException

Tags: json, http, rest

Estou com um problema para utilizar a biblioteca **httpclient**, está acontecendo a excessão:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpException

Não sei se também estou utilizando a biblioteca certa, verifiquei que existem outras bibliotecas que tratam o problema como a **[Apache HttpClient 4.3.6 API](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/)** e DefaultHttpclient (que acho que é do jboss). Uso o **[HttpClient 3.1 API](https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/)**.

### Pilha do  Erro

> 11:10:47,773 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.ClassLoading] (MSC service thread 1-3) catching: org.jboss.weld.resources.spi.ResourceLoadingException: Error loading class br.gov.ro.portovelho.semfaz.sisfiscal.persistence.EnderecoDAO
>       at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.loadClass(ClassTransformer.java:167) [weld-core-1.1.13.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.13.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.loadWeldClass(BeanDeployer.java:116) [weld-core-1.1.13.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.13.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClass(BeanDeployer.java:79) [weld-core-1.1.13.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.13.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClasses(BeanDeployer.java:135) [weld-core-1.1.13.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.13.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.createBeans(BeanDeployment.java:184) [weld-core-1.1.13.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.13.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:349) [weld-core-1.1.13.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.13.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:63) [jboss-as-weld-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
>   **Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpException**
>       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
>       at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
>       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
>       at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$4.work(SecureReflections.java:105) [weld-core-1.1.13.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.13.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$4.work(SecureReflections.java:102) [weld-core-1.1.13.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.13.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52) [weld-core-1.1.13.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.13.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAndWrap(SecureReflectionAccess.java:63) [weld-core-1.1.13.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.13.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.getDeclaredFields(SecureReflections.java:102) [weld-core-1.1.13.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.13.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldClassImpl.(WeldClassImpl.java:155) [weld-core-1.1.13.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.13.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldClassImpl.of(WeldClassImpl.java:121) [weld-core-1.1.13.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.13.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformTypeToWeldClass.apply(ClassTransformer.java:59) [weld-core-1.1.13.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.13.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformTypeToWeldClass.apply(ClassTransformer.java:50) [weld-core-1.1.13.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.13.Final-redhat-1]
>       at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingValueReference.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:358)
>       at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:184)
>       at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:153)
>       at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:69)
>       at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingMapAdapter.get(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:396)
>       at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.loadClass(ClassTransformer.java:163) [weld-core-1.1.13.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.13.Final-redhat-1]
>       ... 11 more
>   **Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpException** from [Module "deployment.sisfiscal.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
>       at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:196) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:444) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:432) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:374) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:119) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
>       ... 29 more

## `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"          xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-  v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>br.gov.ro.portovelho.semfaz</groupId>
    <artifactId>sisfiscal</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.5</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name></name>
    <description></description>
    <url></url>

    <parent>
        <groupId>br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle</groupId>
        <artifactId>demoiselle-jsf-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
    </parent>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle</groupId>
            <artifactId>demoiselle-jpa</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- If you are using a JTA transaction then use this extension -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle</groupId>
            <artifactId>demoiselle-jta</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>



         <!-- Demoiselle Components -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.component</groupId>
            <artifactId>demoiselle-report</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.component</groupId> 
            <artifactId>demoiselle-authorization</artifactId> <version>2.0.2</version> 
            <scope>compile</scope> </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.component</groupId>
            <artifactId>demoiselle-validation</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Bibliotecas específicas da aplicação -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.component</groupId>
            <artifactId>demoiselle-junit</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces-mobile</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6</version>
        </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacc</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency> -->
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.geocoder-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>geocoder-java</artifactId>
            <version>0.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.aerogear</groupId>
            <artifactId>unifiedpush-java-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-installed-adapter</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-beta-2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>  
            <version>2.7</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

## `EnderecoDAO`

```
package br.gov.ro.portovelho.semfaz.sisfiscal.persistence;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpException;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethod;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

import br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.stereotype.PersistenceController;
import br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.template.JPACrud;
import br.gov.ro.portovelho.semfaz.sisfiscal.domain.Endereco;

@PersistenceController
public class EnderecoDAO extends JPACrud<Endereco, Long> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    Endereco endereco;

    public Endereco getBuscaEndPorCEP(String cep) {

        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();


        HttpMethod method = new GetMethod("http://correiosapi.apphb.com/cep/" + cep);


        try {
            httpClient.executeMethod(method);
        } catch (HttpException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        String responseBody;

        try {
            if(method.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==HttpStatus.SC_PROXY_AUTHENTICATION_REQUIRED){ 
                return endereco = getBuscaEndPorCepComProxy(cep);
            }

            responseBody = method.getResponseBodyAsString();

            //2. Convert JSON to Java object
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            endereco = mapper.readValue(responseBody, Endereco.class);


        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return endereco;
    }

    private Endereco getBuscaEndPorCepComProxy(String cep){


        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.getParams().setAuthenticationPreemptive(true);
        //httpClient.getState().setProxyCredentials(new AuthScope("PROXY_ADDRESS", 8080, "PROXY_ADDRESS"), new NTCredentials("LOGIN", "PASS","LOCAL_MACHINE_IP","PROXY_ADDRESS"));
        httpClient.getState().setProxyCredentials(new AuthScope("10.1.1.2", 3128, "10.1.1.2"), null);
        //httpClient.getState().setProxyCredentials(new AuthScope("10.101.1.250", 3128, "10.101.1.250"), new NTCredentials("261537", "260603","10.200.3.47","10.101.1.250"));
        httpClient.getHostConfiguration().setProxy("10.1.1.2", 3128);
        HttpMethod method = new GetMethod(
                "http://correiosapi.apphb.com/cep/" + cep);


        try {
            httpClient.executeMethod(method);
        } catch (HttpException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        String responseBody;

        try {
            responseBody = method.getResponseBodyAsString();

            //2. Convert JSON to Java object
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            endereco = mapper.readValue(responseBody, Endereco.class);


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return endereco;
    }

}
```

## `EnderecoBC`

```
package br.gov.ro.portovelho.semfaz.sisfiscal.business;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.model.SelectItem;

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpException;

import br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.stereotype.BusinessController;
import br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.template.DelegateCrud;
import br.gov.ro.portovelho.semfaz.sisfiscal.domain.Endereco;
import br.gov.ro.portovelho.semfaz.sisfiscal.domain.EnumTipoEndereco;
import br.gov.ro.portovelho.semfaz.sisfiscal.persistence.EnderecoDAO;

@BusinessController
public class EnderecoBC extends DelegateCrud<Endereco, Long, EnderecoDAO> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    public List<SelectItem> getEnumTipoEndereco() {
        List<SelectItem> varEnumTipoEndereco = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
        for (EnumTipoEndereco eachEnumTipoEndereco : EnumTipoEndereco.values()) {
            varEnumTipoEndereco.add(new SelectItem(eachEnumTipoEndereco));
        }
        return varEnumTipoEndereco;
    }

    /** @param cep 
     * <P> Este método busca um cep de um serviço rest 
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public Endereco getBuscaEndPorCEP(String cep){
        return getDelegate().getBuscaEndPorCEP(cep);
    }

}
```

## `EnderecoEditMB`

```
package br.gov.ro.portovelho.semfaz.sisfiscal.view;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.model.SelectItem;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpException;

import br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.annotation.PreviousView;
import br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.stereotype.ViewController;
import br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.template.AbstractEditPageBean;
import br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.util.Beans;
import br.gov.ro.portovelho.semfaz.sisfiscal.business.EnderecoBC;
import br.gov.ro.portovelho.semfaz.sisfiscal.domain.Endereco;

@ViewController
@PreviousView("./endereco_list.jsf") 
public class EnderecoEditMB extends AbstractEditPageBean<Endereco, Long> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private EnderecoBC enderecoBC;

    @Inject
    private Endereco endereco;

    public Endereco getEndereco() {
        return endereco;
    }

    public void setEndereco(Endereco endereco) {
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }

    public List<SelectItem> getTipoEndereco() {
        return enderecoBC.getEnumTipoEndereco();
    }

    public void buscaEnderecoPorCep(){
        String cep = endereco.getCep();
        //String cep = getEndereco().getCep();
        //this.endereco = enderecoBC.getBuscaEndPorCEP("76821348");
        if(cep.length() == 8) this.endereco = enderecoBC.getBuscaEndPorCEP(cep);
    }

    @Override
    public String delete() {
        this.enderecoBC.delete(getId());
        return getPreviousView();
    }

    @Override
    public String insert() {
        this.enderecoBC.insert(this.getBean());
        return getPreviousView();
    }

    @Override
    public String update() {
        this.enderecoBC.update(this.getBean());
        return getPreviousView();
    }

    @Override
    protected Endereco handleLoad(Long id) {
        return this.enderecoBC.load(id);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Você está incluindo todas as bibliotecas que vem junto com a *HttpComponents*? Pois além do .jar `HttpClient`, existem várias outras dependências como pode ver [nessa imagem](http://i.imgur.com/tEtMdsq.jpg).

Answer (score 2):

O **Apache HttpCliente 3.x** é uma versão antiga e deve ser substituída pele [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/).

Analisando suas configurações percebi que você misturou as duas versões das bibliotecas Apache. O Maven vai trazer dependências incorretas ou desatualizadas.

Remova esta entrada do seu `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Além disso, vejo nos seus imports que sua implementação está usando as classes da versão antiga da biblioteca. Provavelmente você pegou algum exemplo da Internet e não sabia dessa diferença.

Olhe a [documentação mais recente](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html#d5e56) e vai encontrar algo assim:

```
HttpRequest request = new BasicHttpRequest("GET", "/",
    HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
```

Sugiro atualizar sua aplicação para as classes mais recentes.